# jqgrid how to detect duplicate rows while adding new row or saving existing row

Tags: validation, jqgrid, duplicates

am using form edit in my jqgrid.  when i add a new row or edit a existing row, i want to do duplicate row validation.  Does jqgrid provide any library or should we write custom code.  does anybody have any code to check if a row already exists?  am using form edit.

Kindly help.  Thanks.

Comment: @Oleg - Can you help me here.  am doing a batch edit and at the time of save, if i check these duplicates, it creates a problem that if some rows are duplicate then the entire transction needs to be rolledback and more importantly, the grid should still show the old values.  instead of this way, what if i can check this duplication at the time of clicking submit button in the popup itself.  when i click submit, if it is a duplicate record(ideally check should happen in client side itself) then display error preventing addign the data back to grid.  is it possible?  Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 3):

$("#gridName").jqGrid('getCol',column_name)

This returns an array of all the values in 'column_name' column.
Just do an inArray() on that to search for your desired value.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but in this way if i have 3 columns, i would have to do that for each column to identify a duplicate row rt... is there any other simple way?

Comment: Well considering that there are 3 columns...so will need to create a function with the above code and call it thrice with arguments grid name, column name and column value. That way this function can be re-usable everywhere to check duplicate values. Also it doesn't make sense to have a single array which will get you values for all 3 columns as that will fetch wrong results. You will ahve to handle each column separately to get the right result. Hope this helps. Let me know if this makes sense else I can explain you more.